# Is there a way to create implicit deeplink in Android Multi-module project using Navigation Component

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-architecture-navigation

I have a multi-module project, where I need to handle deep-linking within the app. The deep-links can be to any feature module with it's own navigation graph. This is a Single - Activity project.

My project includes modules for feature 1, feature 2, and main app module that depends on the two  feature modules. Each of these modules contain their own navigation graph to maintain their own flows. I am trying to create an implicit deeplink, as seem in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-deep-link#implicit)

My app module's navigation graph has nested feature 1 and 2s graphs like below

```xml
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/navigation_main"
    app:startDestination="@id/start_destination"
    tools:ignore="UnusedNavigation">

    <include app:graph="@navigation/navigation_feature_one" />
    <include app:graph="@navigation/navigation_feature_two" />
```

I have the deeplink for feature one defined in the navigation graph - navigation_feature_one

```
<navigation>
...
    <fragment android:id="@+id/featureOneFragment"
              android:name="com.app.featureone.presentation.SomeFragment"
              tools:layout="@layout/some_fragment"
              android:label="@string/title_some_fragment">
        <deepLink app:uri="www.example.com/featureone"/>
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

In the AndroidManifest, I have indicated that the main navigation which has nested graphs should be used

```
<activity
    android:name=".presentation.NavigationActivity"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data android:host="www.example.com"/>
        <data android:scheme="https"/>
        <data android:scheme="http"/>
    </intent-filter>
    <nav-graph android:value="@navigation/navigation_main" />
</activity>
```

I am expecting the project to deeplink into any module within the app using navigation component, but I get an error during compilation that the included graphs cannot be found

```
Referenced navigation file with navigationXmlId = navigation_feature_one not found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue looks like it could be a manifestation of this bug https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/112513722

The issue tracker suggests this as a workaround:

```
// Copy these to the app module's build.gradle
task copyChildNavigationGraphs(type: Copy) {
    from '../feature-module/src/main/res/navigation'
    into 'src/main/res/navigation'
}
preBuild.dependsOn copyChildNavigationGraphs
```

Comment: It seems I need to do that copy for each navigation graph that is in a feature module. I hope they resolve this issue quickly as this does seem hacky

Comment: @aaronmarino I'm still facing this issue in AS 4.1 Whereas the issue you reffer to was marked fix. Can you please confirm if you were able to get rid of the above solution on latest AS and was the build successful for you?